# Import Jquery script to JSP page from Maven repository

Tags: jquery, maven, jsp

I am trying to import jquery script to my jsp page from maven repository. But it is not working. Please find the details below

My pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

I have this jar in my .m2 folder as well.

My jsp code:(I have tried the following ways which I found in net but dint help)

```
<SCRIPT    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT> //did not work


<SCRIPT src="webjars/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT> // did not work
```

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Servlet2 for example, you have to Register `WebjarsServlet` in your `web.xml`:

```
<!--Webjars Servlet-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebjarsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.webjars.servlet.WebjarsServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebjarsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webjars/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please refer to documentation to config correctly webjars with other frameworks spring-boot...
http://www.webjars.org/documentation